# extra chars with emacs -nw

Tags: text-editing

when emacs -nw opens a file from term (gnome-terminal, alacritty), there are extra chars like
**[I**

If I move the mouse in and out of the terminal, we get more of these **[I[I[I**

(the brackets can be paired when using smartparens)

I resolved this to some extent with -Q and by removing for smartparens
**(sp-pair "[" "]" :wrap "M-[")**

from reading a [post](https://superuser.com/questions/729366/emacs-adding-strange-characters-at-the-beginning-of-files) where someone had discovered that was the culprit.

however, running nnn filemanager, sometimes requires moving to the $EDITOR which is emacs -nw and neither of the above has any effect and I'm getting at the beginning.:
**65;7202;1c**

If I set EDITOR=mg, it opens cleanly with no issues.

I would like to know:

1. what is causing this behavior
2. what those chars are (some ascii codes?)
3. how to stop it

Comment: What is TERM set to? what happens when you use `xterm`?

Comment: TERM=xterm-256color and xterm does NOT cause the same problem. could it be because the color setting on TERM applies properly to xterm, but not gnome-terminal?

Comment: yeah, sounds like a combination of terminal and window manager. a bit surprised about alacritty misbehaving. i really only do Linux remotely anymore, so my best advice is 1) make sure TERM=xterm-256color is set, and use an "old" terminal (ie. xterm/aterm/rxvt/urxvt). i've never found the VTE based terminals to be any good

Comment: for what it's worth, i dropped alacritty, and kitty. both were good, but there was too much "special casing" w/ various apps. now if i have a choice my descending choice is `foot` → `st` → `urxvt` → `xterm`